# Vue js: toast position not changing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

in my bootstrap vue js code below, i'm getting toast successfully but the is appears as full width at the very bottom of the page and i couldn't figure out why is this happening, while i'm setting it to top as you can see in the code ..
can someone please help me in this?
thanks in advance

code below in app.js:

```js
<template>
  
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
 
let socket = io("https://**********.herokuapp.com/");
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      user2: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")),
      count: 0,
      today: null,
    };
},
  async created() {
    console.log(this.count);
    const response = await axios.get(
    ********i.herokuapp.com/users/api/${this.user2._id}/`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("user"),
        },
      }
    );

    socket.emit("user_connected", this.user2.username);

    socket.on("verify_connection", (data) => {
      this.verify_connection = data;
      console.log(data,"s")
    });

       socket.emit("user_connected", this.user2.username);
    socket.on("verify_connection", (data) => {
          console.log("heyy", data);
      this.verify_connection = data;
    });
    socket.on("updated_flat", (data) => {

      console.log("heyy", data);
      this.makeToast("sucess", "'b-toaster-top-center");
  
     
    });
     socket.on("test", (data) => {
      
      console.log("heyy", data);
 
    }); 
 ;},
  
 methods: {

    //   playSound() {
    //   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    //   audio.play();
    // },

      getNewCount(data) {
      this.count = data;
    },
     makeToast(variant = null, toaster, append = false) {
      this.$bvToast.toast(" new notification", {
        title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
        variant: variant,
        autoHideDelay: 10000,
        toaster: toaster,
        appendToast: append,
      });
      // this.playSound();
      this.count = this.count + 1;
    },
 
 }}

</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Could you please share the output of your code? Your snippet is not working. Please consider not using it and just share the useful part of your code.

Comment: output of the code is a transparent toast with x close mark only .. since data is coming from API i couldn't share all the code @ImanShafiei

Comment: Thanks, can you share the version of your bootstrap-vue and bootstrap?